# Пакет-кулек-мешок

Tags: синонимы

Как-то в магазине на просьбу дать к купленному товару кулечек продавщица отозвалась: "Девушка, это не кулечек! Это мешочек!"
А есть ли разница?))) В смысле, являются ли слова "пакет", "кулек" и "мешок" синонимами?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Очень интересный вопрос. В Москве в магазинах всегда спрашивали, нужен ли мне пакет... Переехала в Киев. Здесь предлагают "кулёк". Я первый раз отказалась от "кулька" (сразу не поняла) и попросила пакет. :))))) Сейчас привыкла.

Я всегда считала, что кулёк - это из бумаги сложенный конус для конфет, печенья, семечек и пр.
Пакет же - полиэтиленовое или бумажное изделие с ручками или без.
Мешок - тканевый или полиэтиленовый и без ручек.

Ещё пакет, он же кулёк, он же мешок, он же целлофан, он же "майка" - разновидностей много. Думаю, что всё это может быть синонимами в обычной жизни.

Целлофан, как я понимаю, это только изделие из полиэтилена: пакет с ручками или без либо скрученный в рулон, фасовочный, для обёртывания чего-либо.

"Майка" - целлофановый пакет с характерными  ручками, напоминает по форме майку.

Может, есть и ещё какие-то виды, было бы интересно узнать.

Comment: >Переехала в Киев. Здесь предлагают "кулек".

Кулёк -- в данном случае, **разговорное** название полиэтиленового пакета. Сижу сейчас и думаю. Так могут в разговоре между собой сказать **покупатели**. Вроде бы, насколько я припоминаю, обычно кассиры говорят следующее: "Дисконтная карта есть? **Пакет** нужен? Спасибо за покупку". Я имею в виду Центральную Украину и Кив в т.ч. Более правильный вариант названия -- пакет.

А моё неуверенное "вроде бы" потому что, как-то не задумывался над такими повседневными вещами. Местные особенности как раз приезжие лучше замечают.

Comment: Я после обсуждения здесь значений чашка/кружка в магазинах внимателней к витринам с посудой присматривался. :-) 

Обнаружил, что в одних витринах высокая цилиндрическая посудина с ручкой подписана как чашка, в других как кружка. Особо удивил один отдел, где приблизительно одинаковой формы вот такие изделия, только разной расцветки, были подписаны одни "чашка", другие, тут же, на расстоянии каких-то сантиметров -- "кружка" ! :-)

.

Это я к чему? Обещаю в ближайшие дни послушать внимательнее работниц украинских супермаркетов и отписаться в этой теме.

Comment: >"Майка" - целлофановый пакет с характерными ручками, напоминает по форме майку.

Ещё хочу добавить, что неправильно называть тонкий полиэтилен целлофаном. Это разные материалы.

Comment: С полиэтиленом и целлофаном согласна, я употребила как синонимы, а это не так. Спасибо, что поправили. 

"Кулек" очень резал слух, поэтому замечала. Не скажу, что во всех супермаркетах, но во многих было. А в маленьких магазинчиках почти всегда. 

Тему о кружках тоже читала и поняла, что я кружку (судя по теме) называю чашкой. Чашка для меня все, что с ручкой. Кроме пивных и жестяных :) тоже буду смотреть в магазинах :)

Comment: А я про "майку" первый раз слышу - у нас в Крыму так не говорят. Но ведь и правда похоже!))  
А по поводу чашек-кружек мне всегда казалось, что кружка — это исключительно для пива или кваса, а все остальное — чашки)))

Comment: Я "майкой" тоже никогда не называю, но продавцы разных видов пакетов используют это слово для различения. И так просто слышала. 

Сама же как-то попала в смешную стуацию. Вижу у женщины крупную табличку "майка" и дальше какой-то дешевый ценник, рисунки симпатичные. Я спрашиваю: "Майки на какой возраст?" она смеялась от души, т.к. пакеты продавала. ))))) По форме майка, а текстуру я не разглядела. Думала, что просто упакованы.

Comment: >Я "майкой" тоже никогда не называю, но продавцы разных видов пакетов используют это слово для различения. И так просто слышала.

Вот-вот. Точно написали. Насколько мне приходилось слышать, слово "майка" говорят большей частью **продавцы**.

>Тему о кружках тоже читала и поняла, что я кружку (судя по теме) называю чашкой. Чашка для меня все, что с ручкой. Кроме пивных и жестяных :)

И для меня так :-)

Жестяные (точнее металлические эмалированные, как кастрюля) -- *кружка*.

А для пива и кваса ещё называют **бокалы**.

Comment: >В Москве в магазинах всегда спрашивали, нужен ли мне пакет... Переехала в Киев. Здесь предлагают "кулек".

**Надюшка**. Вообще **ОЧЕНЬ интересно** было бы сравнение киевского русского языка и московского русского языка.

Comment: @Nikolja, учитывая как все представители Украины на форуме, определяют слова кружка и чашка, разница как минимум в этих словах присутствует.

Comment: @Nikolja Сразу сложно вспомнить, но разница между русским языком в Москве и Киеве есть. "Кулек" сразу заметила. Еще здесь "подъезд" называют "парадная", а "бордюр" - "поребрик" (как в СПб). "Кулич" пасхальный - "паска". "Формочки" для песка - тоже "паски". (Это я писала в другом вопросе). Вот вроде и все замечания.


Еще из просторечных выражений здесь часто слышу "я за ним соскучился" (вместо "по нему") и "я с него смеялся" (вместо "над ним" или "из-за его шуток/действий")

Answer (score 1):

Кулек и пакет - это я понимаю. 
Хотя и различаю. Пакет - большой, с ручками. А кулек - просто прозрачная целофановая обертка. 
Майка - тоже могу понять, но сама вряд ли скажу.
А мешочек звучит странно. Это только матерчатый или большой, размером с тот, куда картошку набивают.

А в российских магазинах чего только сейчас не услышишь. В Москве кроме кавказцев торгуют в основном украинцы, на них нельзя ориентироваться. Та же картина во многих крупных городах.

Answer (score 1):

Пакет эта любая упаковка, мешок из мешковины, куль это то, что герметично упакует содержимое, от того и надувается как "куля" при попадании внутрь воздуха или другого содержимого, когда закрывается, запечатывается, запаивается. По сути пакет что-либо для держания http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/eng_rus/675052/pocket, кулёк это уже славянское слово.

Answer (score 0):

В Молдавии всегда (и в СССР и сегодня) эти слова имели и имеют такой смысл:
КУЛЁК - это целлофановый мешок, который выдают на кассе в магазине, в который складываешь продукты.
ПАКЕТ - это мешочек из тонкого картона/бумаги - слабый, рвущийся.

Comment: Вряд ли все так однозначно дпже в Молдавии. Просто эти вещи очень близки и, понятно, могут путаться. Я вот не уверен, как оно было десять лет назад в Москве...